# ios sdk show alert without launching the app

Tags: ios, ios4, ios6

I have incorporated custom URL feature in my ios application. I would like to pop an alert on the browser itself when the application is relaunched from a screen other than home screen. I know if the app is relaunched from home screen or not. I am now popping an alert in the application it self. I want to throw the alert with out launching the application may be on the browser itself.

Thanks.

Comment: try this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html

Comment: Can you please explain it a little bit more? What do you mean by `alert on the browser itself when the application is relaunched`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is not possible, as when you are firing the URL, the control is in iOS Safari app. (Not in our custom app), and whatever you can do is - write code in your app only. So until your app gets launched, your code will not get to run, and alert won't be shown.

I am not sure if there is any other way around, this is just my own thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can not do **ANY** UI stuff without having you app running, this will not be possible.

Comment: What about making an HTTP request to a server that triggered a remote push notification, and then forwarded the user to the custom URL scheme after a sleep period?

Comment: not with arbitrary links it wouldn't. only with links you can control. else... how would you do this forwarding?